# I want to create an equation from a graph that i created.

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I made a graph that shows the distance to the center of a heart for each angle of rotation. I want to use this for the code I am writing, but that isn't quite so relevant right now. Now I want to create a function like **y = x**. x goes from 1 to 360, and y changes like this:

[image: Graph that I want to turn into an equation]

I could include it in other ways, but this is the approach I want to use because this approach can be useful for more variety.

here are all the y coordinates:

0,7222222
0,7301587
0,7222222
0,7142857
0,7142857
0,7063492
0,6984127
0,6984127
0,6904762
0,6984127
0,6904762
0,6825397
0,6825397
0,6825397
0,6746032
0,6746032
0,6746032
0,6666667
0,6746032
0,6666667
0,6666667
0,6666667
0,6666667
0,6587301
0,6666667
0,6587301
0,6587301
0,6507937
0,6587301
0,6587301
0,6507937
0,6507937
0,6587301
0,6587301
0,6587301
0,6507937
0,6587301
0,6587301
0,6587301
0,6587301
0,6587301
0,6587301
0,6666667
0,6666667
0,6666667
0,6666667
0,6666667
0,6666667
0,6666667
0,6666667
0,6746032
0,6746032
0,6825397
0,6825397
0,6825397
0,6825397
0,6825397
0,6904762
0,6904762
0,6984127
0,6984127
0,7063492
0,7063492
0,7063492
0,7142857
0,7142857
0,7222222
0,7301587
0,7222222
0,7380952
0,7380952
0,7460318
0,7460318
0,7539682
0,7539682
0,7619048
0,7619048
0,7698413
0,7777778
0,7777778
0,7857143
0,7936508
0,7936508
0,7936508
0,8015873
0,8095238
0,8174603
0,8253968
0,8253968
0,8333333
0,8412699
0,8412699
0,8492063
0,8492063
0,8571429
0,8650793
0,8650793
0,8730159
0,8809524
0,8809524
0,8888889
0,8968254
0,9047619
0,9047619
0,9126984
0,9126984
0,9206349
0,9285714
0,9285714
0,9365079
0,9444444
0,9444444
0,952381
0,952381
0,9603174
0,968254
0,968254
0,9761904
0,9761904
0,984127
0,984127
0,984127
0,984127
0,9920635
0,9920635
0,9920635
0,9920635
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
0,9920635
0,9920635
0,984127
0,9920635
0,9761904
0,968254
0,968254
0,968254
0,952381
0,952381
0,9444444
0,9285714
0,9206349
0,9126984
0,9047619
0,8809524
0,8730159
0,8571429
0,8412699
0,8412699
0,8253968
0,8095238
0,7936508
0,7777778
0,7619048
0,7460318
0,7222222
0,7142857
0,6904762
0,6825397
0,6666667
0,6428571
0,6349207
0,6190476
0,5952381
0,5873016
0,5714286
0,5634921
0,5396826
0,531746
0,5238096
0,515873
0,5
0,4920635
0,5
0,515873
0,5238096
0,531746
0,5396826
0,5634921
0,5714286
0,5873016
0,5952381
0,6190476
0,6349207
0,6428571
0,6666667
0,6746032
0,6904762
0,7142857
0,7222222
0,7460318
0,7619048
0,7777778
0,7936508
0,8095238
0,8253968
0,8412699
0,8412699
0,8571429
0,8730159
0,8809524
0,9047619
0,9126984
0,9206349
0,9285714
0,9444444
0,952381
0,952381
0,968254
0,968254
0,968254
0,9761904
0,9920635
0,984127
0,9920635
0,9920635
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
0,9920635
0,9920635
0,9920635
0,9920635
0,984127
0,984127
0,984127
0,984127
0,9761904
0,9761904
0,968254
0,968254
0,9603174
0,952381
0,952381
0,9444444
0,9444444
0,9365079
0,9285714
0,9285714
0,9206349
0,9126984
0,9126984
0,9047619
0,9047619
0,8968254
0,8888889
0,8809524
0,8809524
0,8730159
0,8650793
0,8650793
0,8571429
0,8492063
0,8492063
0,8412699
0,8412699
0,8333333
0,8253968
0,8253968
0,8174603
0,8095238
0,8015873
0,7936508
0,7936508
0,7936508
0,7857143
0,7777778
0,7777778
0,7698413
0,7619048
0,7619048
0,7539682
0,7539682
0,7460318
0,7460318
0,7380952
0,7380952
0,7222222
0,7301587
0,7222222
0,7142857
0,7142857
0,7063492
0,7063492
0,7063492
0,6984127
0,6984127
0,6904762
0,6904762
0,6825397
0,6825397
0,6825397
0,6825397
0,6825397
0,6746032
0,6746032
0,6666667
0,6666667
0,6666667
0,6666667
0,6666667
0,6666667
0,6666667
0,6666667
0,6587301
0,6587301
0,6587301
0,6587301
0,6587301
0,6587301
0,6507937
0,6587301
0,6587301
0,6587301
0,6507937
0,6587301
0,6587301
0,6587301
0,6507937
0,6587301
0,6587301
0,6666667
0,6587301
0,6666667
0,6666667
0,6666667
0,6666667
0,6746032
0,6666667
0,6746032
0,6746032
0,6746032
0,6825397
0,6825397
0,6825397
0,6904762
0,6984127
0,6904762
0,6984127
0,6984127
0,7063492
0,7142857
0,7142857
0,7222222
0,7301587

Comment: How is the heart originally given? Have you got an equation for it?

Comment: You should include the actual question in the body of the post. It would also help if you can be a little more specific what you mean by "create an equation". There are lots of potential answers that you're going to get, but without knowing e.g. how you intend to use the answer it's going to be hard to give you what you're looking for.

Comment: A function, to be exact. for example something like: **y = a(x - d)² + e**

Comment: you should put that in the body of the post, as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with [parametric equation for the heart symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_(symbol)),
with the help of `linest()` spreadsheet function,
the following cubic formula for the one of symmetric parts of the shape
seems to be more-or-less suitable:

\begin{align} 
f(x)&=a_3\,x^3+a_2\, x^2+a_1\, x+a_0
,
\end{align}
where the coefficients are defined as

\begin{align} 
a_3&=0.00001932
,\\
a_2&=-0.00580493
,\\
a_1&=0.48038548
,\\
a_0&=5
.
\end{align}

This is its plot:
[image]

And this is the heart shape reconstructed using $f(x)$:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about you try this via Lagrange interpolation. I went on [this site](https://www.dcode.fr/lagrange-interpolating-polynomial). And I plugged in some values based on a rough visual scan of your plot:

$$(1, 90) (31, 80) (141, 127) (171, 80) (181, 60) (191, 80) (221, 127) (331, 80) (361, 90)$$

Yielding this beautiful monstrosity:

$$-\frac{(299989 x^8)}{2127365856000000000} + \frac{(54298009 x^7)}{265920732000000000} - \frac{(64524305453 x^6)}{531841464000000000} + \frac{(10132698841093 x^5)}{265920732000000000} - \frac{1439473618836983 x^4)}{212736585600000000} + \frac{(177514529347798123 x^3)}{265920732000000000} - \frac{(17367748928219890513 x^2)}{531841464000000000} + \frac{(49383456898396535293 x)}{88640244000000000} - \frac{106143199760481469}{243936000000000}
$$

_____________ Edit ______________

Unfortunately this plot isn't looking too healthy- perhaps we need more points. I'll leave it up to the OP if this method is to be pursued further. Here's the plot of the interpolating polynomial from Wolfram Alpha:

[image: Wolfram Alpha Plot of Interpolating Polynomial]